# How to get information on specific .snap

Tags: ubuntu-core

While beginning to experiment with Snappy Ubuntu Core I find it very difficult to gather information (this might be a general problem, there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on the platform itself, only for Snap-Developers).

The actual question:

Is there a website like http://packages.ubuntu.com/ or https://github.com/docker-library for snaps?

Information I'd like to get:

- snap maintainer (email)
- changelog
- bug reports
- snap contents (file list, versions of packaged applications)

Answer (score 2):

We're working on improving documentation for 16.04 especially for people wanting to play with the kernel and follow the project ,  in the mean time feel free to post questions on mailing list for fast response...

Answer (score 1):

What metadata is available server-side is documented in the [CPI docs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppStore/Interfaces/ClickPackageIndex). I don't think anybody will be giving out their email address, but a per-package support URL is provided, as is a changelog; bug reports depend on the developer. You can't get contents without getting the snap.

What're you building?

Answer (score 0):

There's [uApp Explorer](https://uappexplorer.com/apps?type=snappy&page=7) which provides information on snaps, much like packages.ubuntu.com. I believe this is run by a third party. It has some of the information you request. It might be worth contacting the operator to see if they can add support for the remaining bits (eg. file listings), since it seems to me that this would be appropriate for the site.